# Next click enable only in 5 seconds'

Tags: jquery

Need to disable the click event for 5 seconds, but do not know how to disable.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert('next click enable  only in 5 seconds');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9cpe4rL/)

Comment: use timeout function. disable the link while click enable after 5 seconds.

Comment: Look into [jquery-throttle-debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the element a class of 'disabled' when it is clicked on. This allows us to both check if the element is currently disabled *and* style it differently:

```js
$('a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('disabled')){
        //I'm disabled, don't do anything.
        return false;
    } else {
        //I'm enabled. Do something:
        alert('next click enabled in 5 seconds');
        //...then mark me as disabled:
        $this.addClass('disabled');
        //...and set a timer to re-enable me:      
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.removeClass('disabled');
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

```css
a {display:inline-block; background-color:green; color:white; padding:4px; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {background-color:red;}
a.disabled {background-color:#ccc; color:#666; cursor:default;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">link 1</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

On click check the button's `.data('disabled')`. If it is true, don't do anything. If it is false disable it for next time. Use `setTimeout` to set the `.data('disabled', false)` after `5000`ms.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.data('disabled')){
        $this.data('disabled', true);
        alert('next click enable  only in 5 seconds');

        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.data('disabled', false);
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9cpe4rL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('a').click(function(){
   jQuery(this).unbind('click')
   setTimeout(function(){ jQuery(this).bind('click');}, 5000);
});
```